# cannot recover mysql idb file

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, recovery, ibdata

I recently have an hdd failure and I try to restore Griffith (https://github.com/micjahn/Griffith) database from a `/var/lib/mysql/griffith` file copy. My new computer uses a more recent version of MySQL:

- original :  5.7.19-0ubuntu
- new :       5.7.20-0ubuntu

I read many a thread about innoDB database recovery and I succeeded to restore many tables but the main table (movies) fails to get restored.

Here is what I do:

1. create a new database
2. find table structure with https://recovery.twindb.com/
3. recreate tables
4. use for all tables:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE;
   ```
5. copy backuped files
6. use for all tables:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE;
   ```

On the last step on the `movies` table, it fails and mysql server terminates.

After some analysis, I found out that the original database was created with utf8 encoding (twindb script was using latin1). But it does not fix the issue.

I also changed mysql config with:

```
innodb_force_recovery=6
```

It helps, doing a `select count(*)` gives some info, but I cannot dump the table to make a *real* backup.

In mysql logs I have this error when running the `IMPORT TABLESPACE` command:

> ```
> [...many errors and warnings...]
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found.
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table `griffith`.`movies` 
> but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats 
> are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 1647523377 in space 238, space name 
> griffith/movies, which is outside the tablespace bounds. 
> Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. 
> If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf
> matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
> ```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the pages in movies.ibd is corrupt, so it can't read it.

I see two options here.

1) There is a script [fetch_data.sh](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb/blob/master/fetch_data.sh) that can copy as many records as possible from a corrupt InnoDB table into a MyISAM table. Start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=6, create a MyISAM table with same structure and use the script to copy records.

2) From the same toolkit use c_parser/stream_parser to fetch records from movies.ibd. You can't import it anyway, because it's corrupt.

Ah, and as a TwinDB author I can suggest one more option :-) - use https://recovery.twindb.com/ to recover movies.ibd. But it's going to cost $$$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The script was running for almost one hour and seems to recover some data. I'll check it out precisely if database is usable. But I think ill will start a new fresh one. And use this one as an archive since it seems well corrupted. Furthermore, in the script can you tell me why you are doing this kind of things: q="INSERT IGNORE INTO \`$newtable\` SELECT * FROM \`$table\` WHERE \`$PK\` >= $1 and \`$PK\` <= $2" and after in the while loop changing `$`a and `$b`. Does doing a simple for loop should be more efficient (and can give precise info on which record is corrupt)?

Comment: A simple loop over  PK range would be slow. Think about a billion records table. On other hand if a..b range is too wide the query will hit a corrupt area.

Comment: So the script varies a and b to be as fast as possible *and* dump all non-corrupt records.